# pytest how to attach runtime info to test item for reporting

Tags: dependency-injection, pytest, pytest-html, pytest-fixtures

I've googled and read most of [pytest documents](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/index.html) but didn't find this topic.
I want to store runtime information(such as *status code* returned from server being tested) in some pytest item properites, to be used in reporting phase, particuarly add some column data in [pytest-html](https://pytest-html.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#extra-content).

Printing to stdout can accomplish similiar goal but I think not elegant nor efficient, since I need to regex extract from the captured text again.
I find [item.stash](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/writing_hook_functions.html#storing-data-on-items-across-hook-functions) maybe a good place to store such information, because it looks straightforward and strong typed. Currently below code works but I'm afraid it's not best practice.

**Working but ugly**:

```py
# in cfgtest.py

status_code_key = pytest.StashKey[int]()
node_item_map = {}

def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    node_item_map[item.nodeid] = item

@pytest.fixture()
def current_item(request):
    return node_item_map[request.node.nodeid]

# use this value in reporting

def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    status_code = item.stash[status_code_key]

# in test_server.py

import pytest
import requests


@pytest.fixture(params=['example.com', 'google.com'], ids=["example", "google"])
def host(request):
    return request.param


def test_status(host, current_item):
    url = f'http://www.{host}'
    status_code = requests.get(url).status_code
    current_item.stash[status_code_key]=status_code
```

One drawbacks is, if the target value is deeply nested in functions calls, the fixture `current_item` cannot be access easily either, unless pass the value along the calling stack.

```py
def internal_methods_called_by_test(url):
    status_code = requests.get(url).status_code
    # if would be great if the item instance can be referenced here
```

Is any better way to write some auto used fixture that can accesse the `item` instance more elegantly? of course, please give one example if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there's no answer yet, and I coincidentally came across [pytest-current-test-environment-variable](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/simple.html#pytest-current-test-environment-variable) in pytest docs, and found solution to access the item anywhere.

```py
def test_status(host):
    # just to demonstrate non-test function
    run_server(host)


def run_server(host):
    url = f'http://www.{host}'
    resp = requests.get(url)
    status_code = resp.status_code
    # env value is like test_attach.py::test_status[google] (call)
    node_id = os.environ['PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST'].replace(' (call)', '')
    current_item = node_item_map[node_id]
    current_item.stash[status_code_key] = status_code
```

This solution is currently satisfying my needs, but still ugly, because I need to split string again, and document says

> The contents of PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST is meant to be human readable and
> the actual format can be changed between releases (even bug fixes) so
> it shouldn’t be relied on for scripting or automation.

Better ideas are still welcome!